# How to manage context/state in a chat bot?

Tags: redis, bots, botframework, telegram-bot, facebook-messenger-bot

I am developing a chat bot using Python, celery, and the MS bot framework. I want to add small dialogs like the following:

> User: Hi
>
> User: Order me fries.
>
> Bot: ok. address?
>
> User: xyz, state, 82288
>
> Bot: Got it. I will order fries for you.

**Here, how can I temporarily store *fries* to access it after the user gives me the address?**

Also, I think it should be acceptable for my use case to forget what the order was if the user does not respond for 2-3 minutes. So, I can also have a timeout for the stored variable.

I thought of using redis. I am thinking of storing something like the following in a redis db:

```
{
 'conversationId':['orderitem':'fries','address':'state, pincode']
}
```

basically a key,value pair with key=conversationId and value='order,address'.

**So, does this look a good option?**

Comment: It's a good choice to use redis, but for better practice, have these in mind: 1. Use json formats for saving data. 2. You should have a timeout for redis data, too. So it's good to save the userdata in a file whenever redis timeouts. Then you can retrieve their state, whenever user comes back again. This way, you never loose users' states.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using the [Bot State REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-state) to manage state within the bot.

The bot can manage 3 types of state data, out-of-the-box:

1. State data for a user on a specific channel (UserData)
2. State data for a conversation on a specific channel (ConversationData)
3. State data for a user within the context of a specific conversation (PrivateConversationData)

Comment: I already went through that. The first paragraph itself ends with the following note: 
**Important**:
`The Bot State service is intended for prototyping only and is not designed for use by bots in a production environment. For performance and security reasons, you should implement your own mechanism for managing state data in the production environment.`

Comment: Here you can see some custom implementations: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/tree/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure